# How to find private AMIs for EC2 deployment using CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I've been trying to deploy a stack using CDK, and need to find the latest available private AMI - security team in my company updates the base images periodically - to comply with security. I have been trying to do the following:

```js
const myAMI = ec2.MachineImage.lookup({
  name: "some-name-*",
  owners: ["1234"],
  filters: { "is-public": ["false"]}
});
```

From the docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.LookupMachineImageProps.html) it seems straight forward, it even says in the notes

```js
// Look up the most recent image matching a set of AMI filters.
// In this case, look up the NAT instance AMI, by using a wildcard
// in the 'name' field:
const natAmi = ec2.MachineImage.lookup({
  name: 'amzn-ami-vpc-nat-*',
  owners: ['amazon'],
});
```

The optional key `filters` seems to be the way to go and uses the `decribeImages` APIs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeImages.html)

**But...** my code snippet above finds nothing, and I have verified that I can find the private AMI using the name and owner.

Comment: The `lookup` method calls the [DescribeImages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeImages.html) API under the hood.  Idea #1:  Try manually running `DescribeImages` yourself from the CLI (outside the CDK) just to confirm you have the inputs right.  Idea #2:  The `lookup` method is meant to call the API once and [cache](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/context.html#context_viewing) the results to `cdk.context.json`.  Make sure a null result wasn't accidentally cached.

Comment: @fedonev I checked using CLI and I can see the AMIs. I suspect the issue might be with the tools I'm using for deployment, but not sure yet. For idea#2, is there a way to force it to clear the cache?

Comment: The context "cache" is just a file with kev-value pairs.  Delete the single key or even the whole file.  Your successful CLI expermiment points to IAM permission issues.